# How can I define a macro that adds a row to a table that has not yet been printed?

Tags: tables, macros, errors, recursion, stack

I want to generate a list of technical abbreviations and acronyms that I use. Currently, I'm defining all acronyms with a macro I have designed. Now, I want the macro to call another macro, called `\addtototaa`, each time it is called, which adds the abbreviation to a table. This other macro is defined as

```
\newrobustcmd{\addtototaa}[2]{\let\OldContent\TableoftaaBody%
    \renewrobustcmd{\TableoftaaBody}{\OldContent #1 & #2 \\}}
```

And then I have the two additional macros

```
\newrobustcmd{\TableoftaaBody}{}
\newrobustcmd{\tableoftaa}[0]{\begin{longtabu}{l X}\TableoftaaBody\end{longtabu}}
```

where `\TableoftaaBody` acts as a storage container for the table contents and `\tableoftaa` prints the table. But when I try to compile the document I get

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] \tableoftaa
```

if I call `\tableoftaa` (but not otherwise). Why do I get this error? I read on [this blog post](http://handyfloss.wordpress.com/2006/11/30/tex-capacity-exceeded-error/) that this message can appear if you have an infinite recursive loop (I guess the function calls are put on the stack and that's why it's eaten up). Have I defined a recursive function here somewhere? By the way, `\addtototaa` is called 31 times before `\tableoftaa` is called, because that's how many acronyoms and abbreviations I have defined, and the two arguments I send to `\addtototaa` are always just literals, and no additional macros.

Comment: In order to adequately assess "why [you] get this error", it would be best to provide a minimal example that illustrates your usage.

Comment: Is there a reason to not just use the glossaries package for this?

Comment: @JM: I actually tried to use the glossary package, but I couldn't figure out how to use it, not even after having read [this guide](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf). The `.glo` file that was generated was empty, which is strange, since I had used both `\makeglossaries`, `\newglossaryentry` and `\printglossaries` and I also have a normal, working index for which I call `makeindex`. Also, I dislike the fact that one have to recompile several times just to see the changes you've made, and then all abbreviations where already defined in alphabetic order.

Comment: @JM: So, do you have any idea of what I might have done wrong, or is it impossible to tell without a code example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to append content to an existing macro using `\gappto` (works similar to `\g@addto@macro`). I've simplified your code snippets so I can make a MWE, but it would most likely be easy to extend to your usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\let\TableoftaaBody\relax
\newcommand{\tableoftaa}{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}\TableoftaaBody\end{tabularx}}

\newcommand{\addtototaa}[2]{%
  \gappto\TableoftaaBody{#1 & #2 \\}%
}
\begin{document}
\addtototaa{1}{\lipsum*[1]}
\addtototaa{2}{\lipsum*[2]}
\addtototaa{3}{\lipsum*[3]}
\noindent\tableoftaa
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, `\gappto` definitely did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

@Werner has shown how to do what you want, so I'll answer the other question: Yes you have defined an infinite recursive loop.

```
\newrobustcmd{\TableoftaaBody}{}

\newrobustcmd{\addtototaa}[2]{\let\OldContent\TableoftaaBody%
\renewrobustcmd{\TableoftaaBody}{\OldContent #1 & #2 \\}}
```

so  `\TableoftaaBody` is eempty then you do

```
 \addtototaa{1}{2}
```

so `\OldContent` is `\let` to `\TableoftaaBody`  so is defined empty and `\TableoftaaBody`  is defined to be

```
\OldContent 1 & 2 \\
```

Then you go

```
 \addtototaa{3}{4}
```

so `\OldContent` is `\let` to `\TableoftaaBody`  so is defined to be `\OldContent 1 & 2 \\`  (oooops!!!!) and `\TableoftaaBody`  is defined to be

```
\OldContent 3 & 4 \\
```

so at this point if you expand `\TableoftaaBody` the first token you see is `\OldContent` so that expands but the first token of that expansion is `\OldContent` again and so you are in an infinite loop. Each time you expand  `\OldContent` you see  `\OldContent` again but push further tokens on the input stream after that, so finally you fill up all available memory.

Comment: I see. I got the idea to do that from the [TeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/let#Examples), but I guess the example featured there never intended you to use the same trick twice to extend a macro.