# How to avoid typesetting any cell if a table is empty

Tags: tables, macros, tex-core

Following [How can I define a macro that adds a row to a table that has not yet been printed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67494/how-can-i-define-a-macro-that-adds-a-row-to-a-table-that-has-not-yet-been-printe), I came up with a macro (`\AddToTable`) that “builds” a table, i.e. appends its argument as the last row of the table.

The problem is that even if I don't invoke *any* `\AddToTable` commands (so that the table should be empty), I still get two vertical separators.

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\let\TableBody\relax
\newcommand{\foottable}{%
  \begin{tabu} {|l|l|} \TableBody \end{tabu}}

\newcommand{\AddToTable}[1]{%
  \gappto\TableBody{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
Test Test Test Test Test\\

\AddToTable{1 & a\\}
\AddToTable{2 & b\\}
\AddToTable{\multicolumn{2}{l}{Text}} % test
\foottable
\end{document}
```

### NOTE:

This question has been heavily edited since it was first posted, so have a look at the edit history if you want to make sense of the comments below (or if you're just curious `:)`).

Comment: Related/duplicate? [How can I define a macro that adds a row to a table that has not yet been printed?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67494/2693).

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence I don't see why this is necessary: Werner's answer defines a command for the table, and the add row macro adds only to that command.  This method can be applied here too.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence But surely making a wrapper is trivial. So the answer applies directly, IMO.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Yes, go ahead ;-)

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thank you, the link was indeed helpful. However, I still have one (minor) problem: I updated my question because it was too long to fit into a comment.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence: Thank you for taking a look at this matter. I don't understand the question you raised, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your followup: A table always has at least one cell. You can simply add a test into your code:

```
  \newcommand{\foottable}{%
    \ifx\TableBody\relax\else
      \begin{tabular} {|l|l|} \TableBody \end{tabular}
    \fi
  }
```

Comment: +1, This fixes my problem. Not really sure if I should accept this answer, though, or even if I should delete my question. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @PierPaolo I think your question can stand as it is, since you modified it an produced a different, but related problem to which this is clearly an answer. (I was just about to post the same, but  yo' beat me to it.) :)

Comment: @PierPaolo Yes, I would.  If you feel up to it you might want to edit your question to remove the original question and keep the part where you tried what I suggested. This would make the question more helpful to others, I think. (And maybe change the title to something more appropriate, since the problem is now what to do with a table with no rows...)

Comment: @AlanMunn So would I. _/me needz teh rap pointz :D_